# -I flag in the makefile does not result in a header file being found

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a file ./src/test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

void Hi() {

std::cout << "Hi, indeed..." << std::endl;
}
```

test.h is located in ./include folder.

This is my makefile:

```
CC = g++

CFLAGS = -Wall

INCLUDES = -I./include

SRCS = $(shell find ./src/ -name '*.cpp')

.PHONY: clean depend

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
OBJS := $(OBJS:./src%=.%)

release: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o app_name $(OBJS)

VPATH = ./src

../%.o: %.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $*.cpp

depend: .depend

.depend: $(SRCS)
        rm -f ./.depend
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $^ > ./.depend;

include .depend
```

As a result I get an error:

```
g++    -c -o test.o ./src/test.cpp
./src/test.cpp:1:18: fatal error: test.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'test.o' failed
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

Also the file `.depend` is completely empty.

How to resolve the issue? The makefile is in root directory:

```
./
makefile
./src/
      test.cpp
      main.cpp
./include/
          test.h
```

Comment: The target of the compile line -- `test.o` -- doesn't match the target in the makefile -- `../%.o` -- that actually makes use of the `INCLUDES` variable.  Looks like your build is invoking a builtin rule.  What's the make invocation you're using and from which directory?

Comment: @G.M. I don't understand what you mean by built-in rule. I just execute 'make' command or 'make release' from the root directory.

Comment: make has its own [builtin or implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) that will be invoked if none of the explicit rules match.  Put the line `.SUFFIXES:` on its own at the top of your makefile and see what changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What G.M. is trying to say is that you have defined a pattern rule that knows how to build a target matching a pattern `../%.o`.  But, when you ask make to build objects, they are of the form `./xxx.o`; e.g., after:

```
SRCS = $(shell find ./src/ -name '*.cpp')
```

suppose `SRCS` contains `./src/foo.cpp`.  Now after this:

```
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
OBJS := $(OBJS:./src%=.%)
```

`OBJS` will contain the value `./foo.o` (by the way, a simpler way to get this behavior is to use the `patsubst` function: `$(patsubst ./src/%.cpp,./%.o,$(SRCS))`).

So, make will try to build the file `./foo.o`.  Since there's no explicit rule for this it will look for an implicit rule.

It sees your pattern rule, but that says how to build `../%.o` which does not match the object file make wants to build `./foo.o`, so your rule is ignored.

Then make will go look for some other implicit rules and it will find the built-in rule that knows how to build a `.o` file from a `.cpp` file, and it will use that.  That rule doesn't use your variable `$(INCLUDES)`, so your compile fails.

You need to either fix your `OBJS` settings to create filenames like `../foo.o` instead of `./foo.o`, if you really want your object files to appear in the parent directory, or else change your pattern rule to build `%.o` not `../%.o`.

Comment: After changing "../%.o" to "%.o" it says: [> g++ -Wall -I./include -c test.cpp
> g++: error: test.cpp: No such file or directory
> g++: fatal error: no input files]     I added these two dots previously when I had header files and cpp files in one src directory. It did the trick back then. I tried to change it to "%.o: ./src/%.cpp" but again "No such file or directory"

Comment: I changed it to [> %.o: ./src/%.cpp
        > -> $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c ./src/$*.cpp] and it's working now.

Comment: Also I have added "$(INCLUDES)" to .depend recipe.